# How to find out which variable is triggering Matlab warning about global variables

Tags: matlab, global-variables

I'm working with Matlab R2018a on Linux. I am getting the warning message:

"Warning: The value of local variables may have been changed to match the globals. Future versions of MATLAB will require that you declare a variable to be global before you use that variable."

The warning is accompanied by file name and line number, but there are several variables on that line, so I wonder to which one the message refers.

Is there a way to find out which variable the warning is complaining about?

Is there a way to turn the warning into an error? Maybe that would make it easier to fix the problem rather than just tolerating it.

Comment: In MATLAB 2017b you do get that warning too, but only if you're actually using the variable *before* you declare it as `global`. And wherever you want to use the global variable, you have to declare it as `global` first! The warning only means that in future versions you cannot write `foo = 3; global foo;` anymore, but you have to declare it as global befor you use it, no matter whether as local or global variable.

Comment: Robert, the line that triggers the warning is one that says something akin to `global foo bar baz`, isn't it? It would be good if you could post the function that generates the warning, and tell us which line it is that generates this warning. I am guessing that it does some computations using a local variable `foo`, and later declares `foo` to be global. Changing the name of the local variable would avoid the warning.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, it's exactly as you guessed. Good work!

Comment: Robert, I have updated my answer, it now indicates a way to find out which variable is causing you trouble.

Answer (score 5):

This error is triggered on a line where you declare a variable to be global, but that variable is already in use as a local variable:

```
baz = 3;
% ... much later...
global foo bar baz
```

To find out which of these variables was already defined, you can set a breakpoint at the `global` line, and see which variables exist at that moment.

You can also add a `who` command just before this line, and observe the console output of your program just before the warning is generated.

Once you found the variable name that is triggering the error, you can rename the *local* variable with that name, leaving the *global* variable unchanged.

<sup>A shoutout to @flawr and @SardarUsama who helped figure out the meaning of this warning message over on the [MATLAB chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/chatlab-and-talktave).</sup>

---

Below is part of the original answer, which shows a way to determine if a variables is global.

---

As [@Durkee suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51030180/7328782), `whos global` will list global variables. You can use this programatically to test for "globalness":

```
~isempty(whos('global','varname'))
```

(note that [`isglobal` used to be a function in MATLAB a long time ago](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/isglobal.html), but has since been removed).

Answer (score 3):

Try typing `whos global` somewhere in your code

```
global global_var
global_var = 1;
clear global_var
whos global
```

It should show all the variables listed as global variables. Regrettably it's not as simple to find where that variable is defined.